# C++11 way of storing a polymorphic object in a class

Tags: c++11, polymorphism, smart-pointers

Before C++11, I would have implemented a class Foo, containing a polymorphic object of base-class Bar as:

```
struct Foo {

  Bar* m_b;

  Foo(Bar* b) : m_b(b) {}

};
```

Following Scott Meyer's advice that raw pointers are bad, I would like to implement `Foo` in the C++11 way, but I don't know how this would look.

I started writing it like

```
struct Foo {

  std::unique_ptr<Bar> m_b;

  Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar> b) : m_b(std::move(b)) {}

};
```

but this has the drawback that `b` has to be dynamically allocated.

So what is the C++11 way of implementing a class containing a polymorphic object?

Comment: Does a `Foo` instance take ownership of the `Bar` its `m_b` points to?

Comment: @ user2357112 Yes, (although I am also interested in hwo to handle the No case)

Comment: why do you think the fact that `Bar` is polymorphic is relevant here?

Comment: @m.s Well because otherwise I would just store the actual object and not a pointer

Comment: @user695652: If a `Foo` takes ownership of its `Bar`, your original code would have leaked the `Bar` object. How would you have dealt with that?

Comment: If `Foo` "owns" the `Bar` then it has to either be dynamic or have some way of knowing how to delete the `Bar`. If its "non-owning" then leave it as a pointer.

Comment: @user2357112 Well I guess there has to be a contract between the user of Foo and Foo. If Bar is dynamically allocated, then yes Foo needs to delete it, otherwise not.

Comment: If `Foo` does not "own" `Bar` (meaning: it doesn't manage it's lifetime) then yes you should use a pointer or reference (reference preferable if possible). There's no specific smart pointer for it unless you use `unique_ptr` with a no-op deleter

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I guess that's what I was confused, so there is not a smart_pointer for every usage-situation of raw pointers?

Comment: @user695652: Smart pointers are for expressing ownership. In codebases which use smart pointers, naked pointers express the *lack* of ownership.

Comment: @user695652: "*If Bar is dynamically allocated, then yes Foo needs to delete it, otherwise not.*" Ownership means "who is required to delete me". If `Foo` takes ownership of the `Bar` it is given, then it is required to delete it. If `Foo` can be given a `Bar` without taking ownership of it, then `Foo` does not own it. So your ownership semantics are conditional, and there is no conditionally-owning smart pointer.

Comment: @user695652 correct. There have been proposals for "dumb" smart-pointers http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3514.pdf (love the title) but I don't see them coming any time soon because they don't add much over a regular pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument that smart pointers are better than raw pointers is ownership based.

The ownership of a resource should be clear from the type system, as it is an easy thing to get wrong, and a hard thing to understand from just reading code.  With it embedded in the type system, you can tell what determines lifetime of an object from its type.

The pre-C++11 code either did not own the `Bar` (it was not responsible for its lifetime), or your code leaked.

The post-C++11 code owns the `Bar` and is in charge of its lifetime.

If you want a state where the `Foo` conditionally owns the `Bar` based off possibly complex runtime logic, and sometimes does not, then the `std` smart pointers are probably not a good idea.

Imagine you had a car prior to the car safety rules.  It had a button that ejected the passenger from the car.  This was fun, and so long as you didn't push the button, was safe.

Now car safety rules are here, and you hear following them is "better".  You come to the car safety Q&A and ask how you can set up a button that ejects your passenger from the car and follow these car safety rules.  They don't seem to permit passenger ejection.  Even if you put a cover on the button, there is something about "what if the car gets in an accident and the button executes incorrectly" and life and limb and other stuff.

How can I have an ejector seat in my car yet get a 5 star safety rating?

The smart pointers make ownership clear.  If you have muddled ownership, then you must clarify it in order to use smart pointers.

There are situations that jusify complex ownership and lifetime semantics.  These are few and far between, and by using smart pointers by default we can avoid the complexities of lifetime *without having to validate it every time*.

```
struct Foo {
  std::unique_ptr<Bar> m_b;

  Foo(std::unique_ptr<Bar> b) : m_b(std::move(b)) {}
};
```

This is a better interface, because the ctor of `Foo` makes it clear it takes ownership.  Taking a raw pointer, and then wrapping it in a smart pointer, makes the interface unclear.